# A socket API return "permission denied" in HAL(C++) at Android development

Tags: android, hal

I am creating new HAL application which use socket access.
However, the socket API return Operation not Permitted in HAL(c++).

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) /// ---> return Operation not Permitted
```

I already confirmed that:

- SELinux is disabled.
- The application belong to the group (AID_INET(3003)).
- In case of root user, the socket API return success.

I investigated kernel code and I suspected that some bpf filter affected it as follow.

packages/modules/Connectivity/bpf_progs/netd.c:

```
DEFINE_NETD_BPF_PROG_KVER("cgroupsock/inet/create", AID_ROOT, AID_ROOT, inet_socket_create,
                          KVER_4_14)
(struct bpf_sock* sk) {
    // A return value of 1 means allow, everything else means deny.
    return (get_app_permissions() & BPF_PERMISSION_INTERNET) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

How to set BPF_PERMISSION_INTERNET permission to the uid of HAL application?

Comment: I realized that HAL can be specified a permission by following file.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/etc/platform.xml:
...
<assign-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" uid="your_uid" />
....

Answer (score 0):

I realized that HAL can be specified a permission by following file.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/etc/platform.xml:

```
...
<assign-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" uid="your_uid" />
....
```

By modification it, the problem was solved.